# Can't use ListView to make Stack Scrollable

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Hello I'm new to flutter and I'm trying to make a stack scrollable
How can I make Scroll Inside a Stack without getting unbound error?
I'm using Stack in another Stack and I'm trying to make First Stack Scrollable

```
Stack(
children:[
   Positioned(
      top:0,
      child:SingleScrollChildView(
         child:firstStack()
      ),
   ),
   Positioned(
      bottom:0,
      child:secondStack(),
   ),
]
)
```

Comment: Please share any code snippet or gif of your idea.. It's helps to get some idea.

Answer (score 0):

first of all a code snippet well be a good idea for anyone to understand what you are going through .
second of all you can wrap your `Stack` with a `SingleChildScrollView` : hope this is helpful

Comment: sorry for that not putting code because I'm changing it all the time 
by the way it doesn't work for me because stack wants to get all the space he can also singlescrollchild so it throws ubounded height for me

Answer (score 0):

If the stack is throwing an unbounded height error, wrap it inside a Container and give it a height. That's what I always do.
Second thing, don't give 0 values to the Positioned widget. If you're using the widget make sure to give at least 2 non-zero values to it.

This is how I'd probably do it:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Positioned(
      top: 10.0,
      left: 10.0,
      child: ListView(
         child: Container(
           height: 120.0,
           child: firstStack(),
         )
      ),
   ),
   Positioned(
      bottom: 0.0,
      right: 10.0
      ListView(
         child: Container(
           height: 120.0,
           child: firstStack(),
         )
      ),
   ),
  ]
),
```